# Django rest framework: which generic APIview to use?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to allow user to get (list), post and delete method in the view? What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods.

For getting the list: `get_queryset(self)`

To save: `perform_create(self, serializer)`

To update: `perform_update(self, serializer)`

To delete: `perform_destroy(self, instance)`

You can ref Document of Django rest framework: [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)